# Rank of a free group times a free abelian group.

Tags: group-theory, free-groups, combinatorial-group-theory, free-abelian-group

I know that the rank (i.e. minimal number of generators) of the product $\mathbb{Z}\times F_2$, of the infinite cyclic and free group on two generators, is three, but the only argument I could quickly piece together uses quite advanced tools (name-bearing and quite recent results on deficiency of a group/presentation). Can anyone point me to a direct, elementary proof, if there is one? Presumably, this (i.e. that the rank is the sum of ranks) also holds for product of a free group of finite rank and any cyclic group/product of cyclic groups?

Comment: Maybe I’m missing the point of the question, but you could look at the abelianization, which is $\mathbb{Z}^3$.  Then $3$ is a lower bound on the number of generators.  This matches the size of a generating set you can construct, so it’s minimal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $G=\mathbb{Z}^n\times F_m$ where $F_m$ denotes the free group of rank $m$.  Consider the [abelianization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_subgroup) of $G$, i.e., the surjective map
$$
\pi:G\twoheadrightarrow G/[G,G]\simeq\mathbb{Z}^{n+m}.
$$
Since this map is surjective, if $\{g_1,\dots,g_k\}$ generate $G$, then $\pi(g_1),\dots,\pi(g_k)$ generate $\mathbb{Z}^{n+m}$.  Since the rank of $\mathbb{Z}^{n+m}$ is $n+m$, this implies that $k\geq n+m$.

On the other hand, we can write down a generating set of $G$ consisting of $n+m$ generators as follows: $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is generated by $n$ coordinate vectors $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ and $F_m$ is, by definition, generated by $m$ elements $\{f_1,\dots,f_m\}$.  Therefore, $G$ is generated by $\{e_1,\dots,e_n,f_1,\dots,f_m\}$.

Since we have shown that it is possible to generate $G$ with $n+m$ generators and, in addition, that any generating set for $G$ must have at least $n+m$ elements, it follows that exactly $n+m$ generators is the best possible, i.e., the rank is $n+m$.

For the further generalization, combining this argument with the fundamental theorem of [finitely generated abelian groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_abelian_group) should provide exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Other generalisations can be found by looking at Right Angled Artin Groups (also called Partially Commutative Groups), which generalise direct products of free groups. The result also holds for these groups.

Comment: Thank you, of course. I (wrongly) discarded abelianization altogether because I just had a discussion about the bad behavior of rank of subgroups after abelizanization and went "clearly, the same problems will arise in this case". Well, of course they don't and the proof is as simple as you describe.